# json.load, and json.loads not working to load JSON file data, Python

Tags: python, json

Please see the following JSON file, I have been trying to read:

```
    [
        {
            "age": "['3']",
            "description": " Depending on the last time your little one was fed ",
            "schedule": "Milk Feed",
            "time": "6:15 am"
        },
        {
            "age": "['3']",
            "description": " Someone's feeling a bit sleepy!",
            "schedule": "Naptime",
            "time": "8:15 am - 9:15 am"
        }
    ][
        {
            "age": "['4']",
            "description": " Depending on the last time your little one was fed ",
            "schedule": "Milk Feed",
            "time": "6:15 am"
        },
        {
            "age": "['4']",
            "description": " Someone's feeling a bit sleepy!",
            "schedule": "Naptime",
            "time": "8:15 am - 9:15 am"
        }
    ]
```

I have tried both with `JSON.load`, and `JSON.loads`

with json.load

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

and with json.loads, I receive following output

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
```

this is my code

```py
    for line in open('baby_schedule.json', 'r'):
        print(json.loads(line))
```

I need your help to load this JSON, and then read individual item in it.

Comment: Welcome. `json.load()` working with file input, `json.loads()` works with buffer. Your json is not valid, btw.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, How can I make it valid?

Answer (score 0):

You json is not valid.
This is the correct version.

You should use `json.loads` with buffers and `json.load` with files

```
[
  {
    "age": "['3']",
    "description": " Depending on the last time your little one was fed ",
    "schedule": "Milk Feed",
    "time": "6:15 am"
  },
  {
    "age": "['3']",
    "description": " Someone's feeling a bit sleepy!",
    "schedule": "Naptime",
    "time": "8:15 am - 9:15 am"
  },
  {
    "age": "['4']",
    "description": " Depending on the last time your little one was fed ",
    "schedule": "Milk Feed",
    "time": "6:15 am"
  },
  {
    "age": "['4']",
    "description": " Someone's feeling a bit sleepy!",
    "schedule": "Naptime",
    "time": "8:15 am - 9:15 am"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you, 
It was helpful suggestion. I have 22 files, that I read and add them in JSON one by one, by calling a function. 
'''
fh = open("../schedule.json", "a+") #open JSON file
fh.write(json.dumps(output_list, indent=4, sort_keys=True)) # dump the list to JSON file
fh.close()  # Close the file
'''

It creates the above shared JSON. Do you think, I am doing any mistake while building a JSON file?

Comment: you are opening the file with the append flag ("a+"), you are appending multiple json structure into one file and this cause the issue you have above. What are you doing is incorrect if you still need to have a readable json.

Comment: I have used built in modes such as w, and w+ but they replace the previous data each time I try to append the JSON.

Comment: You need to 1) read the file and parse it in python structures as json.loads does, 2) add the new data into the parsed structure, 3) save the data into the file. In this way, you'll have a redabled json file with the old and new data inside

Comment: Thank you Yosef! Your suggestion was very helpful. I fixed my JSON file and its working good now. :)